# How do you convert a certain Date back to Javascript's full string date format?

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, momentjs

Basically I want to turn this:

```
2018-10-23T08:00:00.000000000Z
```

into this format:

```
Thu Aug 22 2013 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

I looked into moment.js but it seems to provide something of the reverse.
Help! Vanilla solutions preferred.

Comment: Did you try `new Date(dateString)`?

Comment: I guess GMT-4 is your local Time?

Comment: @Nikolaus im Easter US Time. This was fetched from an api and sometimes time zones are a bit different.

Comment: @Rajesh   Yes but it just gave me the original string back in console.log

Comment: For that to work in the console you need to call `.toString()` on the Date object.

Comment: `new Date('2018-10-23T08:00:00.000000000Z').toString()` ?

Comment: i see. Thanks everyone , .toString() worked.

Comment: Note that the input timestamp format is not consistent with ECMA-262, so implementations are free to return an invalid date if they wish. Don't rely on the built–in parser.